# Getting django.db.utils.DatabaseError while using djoser password reset email

Tags: python, django, djoser

I'm trying to make a authentication system using djoser. Signup and Signin API endpoints are working fine but when I send a request to the backend for password reset email it is throwing this error.

```
Internal Server Error: /auth/users/reset_password/
Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 51, in execute  
    self.result = Query(
                  ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 876, in parse
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)    
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 933, in _select
    return SelectQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params) 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 116, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 152, in parse
    self.where = WhereConverter(self, statement)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\converters.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\converters.py", line 119, in parse
    self.op = WhereOp(
              ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\operators.py", line 476, in __init__
    self.evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\operators.py", line 465, in evaluate
    op.evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\operators.py", line 465, in evaluate
    op.evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\operators.py", line 279, in evaluate
    raise SQLDecodeError
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:      

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: ('SELECT "server_useraccount"."id", "server_useraccount"."password", "server_useraccount"."last_login", "server_useraccount"."is_superuser", "server_useraccount"."email", "server_useraccount"."name", "server_useraccount"."is_staff", "server_useraccount"."is_active" FROM "server_useraccount" WHERE ("server_useraccount"."email" = %(0)s AND "server_useraccount"."is_active") LIMIT 21',)
        Params: (('vanumdaniel7@gmail.com',),)
        Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute  
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)  
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) 
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djoser\views.py", line 233, in reset_password
    user = serializer.get_user()       
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djoser\serializers.py", line 130, in get_user
    user = User._default_manager.get(  
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1169, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)        
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors: 
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\daniel.vanum\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in execute  
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

This is my serializers.py

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "email", "name")
```

This is my settings.py

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours = 6),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days = 1),
}

DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'server.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'server.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer'
    },
}
```

This is my models.py

```
class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password = None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email = email, name = name)
        password = getenv("defaultUserPassword")
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        send_mail(
            "Account successfully created",
            f"Hi {name}, you can successfully login to our website using these credentials. username: {email}, password: {password}. Please change your password at the login page.", 
            recipient_list = [user], 
            from_email = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
        )
        return user
```

Request I'm making to the backend from react

```
const result = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/auth/users/reset_password/", {
                method: "POST",
                mode: "cors",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                }
            });
```

Note: if I send the same request through postman I'm getting the following response:

```
TypeError at /auth/users/reset_password/
```